# Customize legend for continuous size in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, customization, legend

I was trying to emphasize some specific size as a reference in my legend. I tried `scale_size_continuous` and `scale_size_manual` without any luck. Below is a toy example, is there anyone who can help with it?

```
set.seed(926)
dat.toy <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(100),
                      x2 = rnorm(100),
                      x3 = factor(sample(1:5,100,replace = T)),
                      x4 = factor(sample(1:4,100,replace = T)))
require(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat.toy,aes(x=x3,y=x4,colour = x1, size = x2)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image: Plot]

The desired result should be able to customize (amplify or shrink) the size of the circle, add the size of the circle for `-3`, delete (hide) the size of the circle for `2` in the legend.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you aware that you are plotting multiple points on top of each other? add `geom_jitter()` to your code to see what I mean.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'customize' the size of a circle, but to choose the points that are shown you can use `scale_size_continuous(limits=c(-3,1),breaks=c(-3,-2,-1,0))` etc

Comment: What's the logic here? Why would you drop a value from your legend?

Comment: @TarJae, I haven't noticed that. Thanks for your tip, they did landed on top of each other. In my real data, this issue doesn't apply. Thanks again.

Comment: @camille, good question! In my real-world problem, the values are from -0.8 to 2.5. But the legend didn't indicate negative values at all, so I like the negative value to be in the legend and make it more clear.

Comment: But why does including negative values mean you'd drop 2 from the scale? Size isn't very intuitive for negative numbers; you might want to scale size to the magnitude of numbers, and use color or some other encoding to show positivity

Comment: @GeorgeSavva, thanks so much! Your solution almost solved my problem. With your hit, I solved it as follows. ` 
  scale_radius(range=c(0,6),
               breaks = -1:2,
               limits = c(-1,3))` 
The range parameter kinda helps with amplifying or shrinking the circle size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this ?

```
require(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat.toy,aes(x=x3,y=x4, color = x1)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size=x2))+
  geom_jitter()+
  scale_size(range = c(-2,4))
```

[image]